# Python: looping over characters in a string when string is changing

Tags: python, string, loops

```
def substitutionEncrypt1(text,key):
    plaintext=text.lower()
    alphabet="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz "
    for ch in plaintext:
        r=plaintext.index(ch)
        plaintext=plaintext.replace(ch,key[r])
    return plaintext
```

my text is "The Quick Brown Fox"
I understand why it doesn't encrypt a substitution cipher properly, but why does python throw an error in the fifth line saying "substring not found"? 
am I not iterating through characters in the plaintext?
the language i'm using is python

thanks!

Comment: Strings never change in Python, they're immutable. With `plaintext = plaintext.replace(ch,key[r])` you're assigning an entierely new string to the name `plaintext`. The `for` loop though will continue to iterate over the sequence that was in `plaintext` at the time the loop started.

Comment: thanks Lukas! your answer was really helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not iterate over something (be it a list, or a set, or a dictionary … you get the idea) that's being modified at the same time - and besides, a string is immutable, so in reality you're creating new strings at each iteration. For implementing a substitution cipher in Python, nothing is easier than using [`translate()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.translate) - and we can make the translation work in both directions:

```
import string

alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz '
subst    = 'edbjvushlpknyxt foqiwacrzgm'

table = string.maketrans(alphabet, subst)
'hello world'.translate(table)
=> 'hvnntmctonj'

table = string.maketrans(subst, alphabet)
'hvnntmctonj'.translate(table)
=> 'hello world'
```

Comment: Probably because you're suggesting that the string is being modified, which it isn't. Iterating over sequences and changing them during iteration only applies to mutable types.

Comment: @LukasGraf there, it's clarified now

Comment: ahh thanks!
"Iterating over sequences and changing them during iteration only applies to mutable types"
^this was extremely helpful!

Comment: @user3881923 and anyway, it's a bad idea - you should never modify a mutable type at the same time that you're iterating over it

Comment: @user3881923 I still feel the answers here aren't terribly clear yet, trying to write one up myself.

Comment: hey, not sure why, but when i try to use translate(), python throws up an error when I do string.maketrans(alphabet,subst), saying that 'module' object has no attribute 'maketrans'. I'm using python 3.4. any idea why? thanks!

Comment: @user3881923 did you import the `string` module? are you sure that you didn't overwrite it with, say, a variable called `string`? start a new session and repeat the steps above from the beginning

Comment: oh it works with str.maketrans(input,output)! just curious, but whether i replace str with input or output it gives me the same result, why is that so? what exactly is str supposed to mean, and are we supposed to put anything in place of str? thank you!!

Comment: oh yeah, sorry about that, i'm new to stack overflow haha. but uh i didn't name any variable str. I'm just wondering why str.maketrans(input,output) and input.maketrans(input,output) and output.maketrans(input,output) gives the same result? what exactly is supposed to go before the full stop? sorry for so many questions><

Comment: I don't know how did you write the code (there's no mention of `input` or `output` in the question), so I can only guess that they are strings. To avoid confusion you should 1) import the string module and 2) use string.xxx to call the xxx method, in this case maketrans()

Answer (score 2):

There's several issues in your code that compound to it not doing at all what you want.

### 1. Strings are immutable in Python

You cannot change a string in Python. Once it's been created, it stays the same.
All you can do is create a new string, possibly based on the original one, and
assign it to the same name.

For example, you can *modify* a `list` (a mutable type) by using slice notation to assign a new element at a certain index:

```
>>> lst = ['one', 'two', 'three']
>>> lst[0] = 42
>>> lst
[42, 'two', 'three']
```

You can't do that with strings, they are immutable:

```
>>> s = 'abc'
>>> s[1] = 42
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

So, all you can do is assign an entirely new string to `s`:

```
>>> s = s.upper()
>>> s
'ABC'
```

So, `upper()`, like `replace()` and all the other string methods, doesn't work *in-place*,
it instead returns a modified *copy* of the string.

<sub>As for the reason for this, see [Why are Python strings immutable?](http://effbot.org/pyfaq/why-are-python-strings-immutable.htm). It basically boils down to performance.</sub>

---

### 2. Your loop doesn't iterate over `s`. It iterates over the value  `s` had when the loop started.

When you do `for item in iterable`, this is what Python does:

- It gets a reference to the value that `iterable` points to (at the start of the loop).

  - If that value is a string, it gets a reference to that exact string. Since you can't
    modify a string, that reference will always point to the same object in memory.
  - If the value is mutable (like a list), the reference will point to that value.
- Every iteration, it fetches the next item from the iterable value that the reference points to.
  If that value is mutable and has changed in the meantime, tough luck, you get weird results.

---

### 3. You shouldn't change mutable sequences while iterating over them

Even if `str` was a mutable type, and you *could* change it, you never should change iterables while iterating over them.

Example:

```
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

for item in lst:
    print item,
    lst.remove(item)
```

Output:

```
1 3 5
```

As you can see, items have been skipped because the list size and the item's respective indexes changed during iteration.

For dictionaries, Python will even explicitely warn you about this and bail out:

```
dct = dict(foo=23, bar=42)

for key in dct:
    print key
    dct['baz'] = 'qux'
```

Output:

```
foo
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "it.py", line 3, in <module>
    for key in dct:
RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration
```

So, keeping all this in mind, if you *were* to implement your code in the way you intended, you'd need to
keep two variables separate from each other, one that you loop over, and one you assign the translated results to.

But since Python already features a [`translate()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.translate) function (as explained in @Óscar López's answer) for exactly that purpose, that's what you should use.

Comment: hey thanks for the really detailed explanation:D
just another question: not sure why, but when i try to use translate(), python throws up an error when I do string.maketrans(alphabet,subst), saying that 'module' object has no attribute 'maketrans'. I'm using python 3.4. any idea why? thanks!